# in express how to specify option for prefix plugin for less?

Tags: node.js, express, less

https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix

this is the plugin that i could use

```
var LessPluginAutoPrefix = require('less-plugin-autoprefix'),
    autoprefixPlugin = new LessPluginAutoPrefix({browsers: ["last 2 versions"]});
less.render(lessString, { plugins: [autoprefixPlugin] })
```

However, In Express... I use less like this `app.use(require('less-middleware')(path.join(__dirname, 'public')..`

so where can i put `plugins: [autoprefixPlugin]` part in express. I am new to less and express so I'm pretty lost.

Answer (score 1):

Version `2.0.0` of `less-middleware` was just released tonight if you would like to give it a try. Something like this should work:

```
var lessMiddleware = require('less-middleware');
var lessPluginAutoPrefix = require('less-plugin-autoprefix'),
    autoprefixPlugin = new lessPluginAutoPrefix({browsers: ["last 2 versions"]});

var app = express();
app.use(lessMiddleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
  render: {
    plugins: [autoprefixPlugin]
  }
}));
```

Comment: css being produced doesn't have prefix properties (user-select, filter were not not prefixed)

Comment: var lessMiddleware = require('less-middleware');
var lessPluginAutoPrefix = require('less-plugin-autoprefix'),
    autoprefixPlugin = new lessPluginAutoPrefix({browsers: ["last 2 versions"]});

app.use(lessMiddleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
  render: {
    plugins: [autoprefixPlugin]
  }
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));